# tkinter: how to use after method in response to another function

Tags: python, tkinter

The general idea of the code is that every one-and-a-half seconds, the text on the buttons changes randomly, so that each reads either ‘click’, ‘clack’ or ‘cluck’.  If the player clicks a button labeled ‘click’, he or she scores 10 points.  If the player clicks a button labeled ‘clack’ or ‘cluck’, he or she loses 10 points.  When a button has been clicked, it changes color—to light green if the click scored points and to light yellow if it lost points.  Clicking the same button again has no effect until the next time the button labels are changed, at which time the colors should also revert to gray.

The problem that I have is modifying the code so that each time the player scores 10 points the interval between label changes is reduced by 50 milliseconds and each time the player loses 10 points the interval is increased by 100 milliseconds.

Here is the original code, but I don't know how to modify the code for the intervals.

```
from tkinter import *
import random 

score = 0 

root = Tk()

scoreFrame = Frame(root)
scoreFrame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

scoreLabel = Label(scoreFrame)
scoreLabel.pack(expand=YES) 

def showScore():
    scoreLabel['text'] = 'Score: {0}'.format(score) 

clickFrame = Frame(root)
clickFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

def changeLabels():
    for button in buttons:
        button['text'] = random.choice(['click', 'clack', 'cluck']) 
        button['bg'] = buttonDefaultColor
    root.after(1500, changeLabels)

def makeButton():
    button = Button(clickFrame)
    def cmd(): 
        global score
        if button['bg'] == buttonDefaultColor:
            if button['text'] == 'click': 
                score += 10
                button['bg'] = 'light green'
            else:
                score -= 10
                button['bg'] = 'light yellow'
            showScore()      
    button['command'] = cmd
    button.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH) 
    return button 

buttons = [makeButton() for i in range(5)] 
buttonDefaultColor = buttons[0]['bg'] 

changeLabels()
showScore()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the 1500 to either a global value or a class property.  Something that can be updated.